# How can I set the device owner on a Samsung device?

Tags: android, device-owner

Similar to the question here, I am trying to set the device owner using adb on a Samsung XCover4

[Not allowed to set the device owner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47093787/not-allowed-to-set-the-device-owner)

Although there are no accounts on the device after a factory reset, the call to

`adb shell dpm set-device-owner`

Still fails with the `Not allowed to set the device owner because there are already some accounts on the device` error.

This works fine on other 'pure android' devices I have tried, so I'm guessing that the Samsung sets the owner during setup in some way.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: I am also facing a similar issue. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: Finally, I found a workaround. You can use QR code to provision the device. https://developers.google.com/android/work/prov-devices#qr_code_method

Answer (score 0):

You can use QR code to provision the device and set device owner:

https://developers.google.com/android/work/prov-devices#qr_code_method

Comment: There are a lot of variables not being addressed here. It's not really a workaround for the issue, unless you fit the specific scenario where you can request (or were given) a QR code.